# Problem running tecplot2017 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, opengl

I am trying to install tecplot2017 on ubuntu 18.04. Everything seems ok until I use the following command to run the program.

```
./tec360
```

Below is what i receive on terminal

```
Tecplot 2017.2.0.79771 - 02:38:39  Apr 25 2017  [linux64-centos6.5]
Configuration File     : /home/kazem/tecplot/360ex_2017r2/tecplot.cfg
Process Temp Dir       : /tmp/tecplot_kazem/tpaxmIoUD
Tecplot internal font file: /home/kazem/tecplot/360ex_2017r2/tecplot.fnt
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open r600 (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open r600 (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error: GLXBadContext 173
  Extension:    156 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 6 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x3200017
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tecplot::ExceptionBase'
  what():  Failed to create GLDrawArea.
```

Any help on this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed appropriate GPU drivers ? I think you have to install AMD drivers for your GPU (hence the error : "failed to open r600" ) . You cannot run that because it cannot use OpenGL functionality of your GPU because currently there's no driver to implement that functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. How is it possible to know whether the appropriate GPU drivers are installed? what  command should i use?

Comment: You can see whether you have AMDGPU driver is use or not via "lsmod | grep -i amd " . And if you have the driver in use but still you get those errors , consider installing the [amdgpupro](https://www.amd.com/en/support) driver. You can see the model of your gpu via "lspci | grep amd " , and download the driver version accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue for the processor other than intel. As [suggested by support](https://kb.tecplot.com/2010/03/09/failed-to-create-opengl-context/), use `./tec360 -mesa` to start the program instead of instead of `./tec360`.